# Get Laravel database connection to work on individual PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.3 for my application and everything works fine. However, I need to create a separate PHP script that will run on its own whenever it's loaded in the browser - lets just say http://test.com/script.php

I have the DB connection all defined in the .env file.

The script lives in the public directory and I need to run a query against the database that my app connects to. Is there a way I can retrieve the database connection to use in the script and if so how?

Comment: Is there a reason you need this to be a separate 'PHP file'? You could use a new route that points to your own separate controller that works as a script. You don't even need to return a view. Just use it like a script.

Answer (score 0):

you should try...

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as DB;
```

and then

```
$result = DB::table([some table])->where([some column], [some identifier])->first();
```

EDIT: I will expand a little.
If your page is not part of the regular routing of Laravel, it is possible it doesn't have access to a lot of the autoloaded classes. I use Eloquent in my website (but I don't use Laravel), and this is how I access the database directly.

Comment: I get  Class 'Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager' not found in when i try that

Comment: you might try including that file (Illuminate/Database/Capsule/Manage.php) from the vendor folder.

Comment: If this is a development app, you could try running "composer dump-autoload -o" in the terminal (at the directory of your app) to see if your script will see the namespaces after autoload.